# PHP select field from nested query

Tags: php, mysql

I am running a query on 2 tables, to return information from a blog. The nested query selects the tags that are associated with that blog, which is a separate table.

I want to be able to get the 'tag' row from the 'tags' table and display these on the page. My code is below and I have commented where I would like the rows to be selected.

```
<?php
include("inc/dbconnection.php");
$id     = $_GET['tag'];
$id     = trim($id);
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "
SELECT * 
  FROM blog 
 WHERE blog_id IN (SELECT blog_id FROM tags WHERE tag = '$id')
");
if (!$result) {
    die("Database query failed: " . mysqli_error($conn));
} //!$result
else {
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($rows > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $content  = $row['content'];
            $content2 = substr($content, 0, 100);
            /* Below is where I would like to pull the row 'tag' from the nested query */
            $rawTag   = $row['tag'];
            $tag      = str_replace(" ", "", $rawTag);
            $tagArray = explode(",", $tag);
            $tag      = "";
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($tagArray); $i++) {
                $tag .= "<a href='tag-" . $tagArray[$i] . ".php'>" . $tagArray[$i] . "</a> ";
            } //$i = 0; $i < count($tagArray); $i++
            echo "
                  <table>
                    <tr>
                      <th>
                        <a href='blog-" . $row['blog_id'] . ".php'>
                          <h2>" . $row['title'] . "</h2>
                        </a>
                      </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <p>" . date("d/m/Y", strtotime($row['createdDate'])) . "</p><br />
                        <span>" . $content2 . "...</span><br />
                        <span><small>Tags: " . $tag . "</small></span>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>";
        } //$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLi_ASSOC)
    } //$rows > 0
    else { //$rows > 0
        echo "<br /><h1>There are currently no blogs with the selected tag (" . $_GET['tag'] . ")</h1><br /><h2>Please check back later.</h2>";
    }
}
?>
```

Sorry if this is a stupid question and thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: Good that you're using a modern API, but now see prepared statements

Comment: Ahhh shoot! Sorry, forgot to mention that -_- I want to display the 'tag' row from a secondary table within my DB... I'll update the question :)

Comment: Correct, I am only using 1 DB, but have 2 tables in it at the moment

Comment: I think it's time to read up on joins. Also, as an aside, I find the choice to call the tag value '$id' a decidedly odd one. What's wrong with $tag?

Comment: What is the structure of the blog table and the tags table?

Answer (score -1):

There are two part one is Query and second is data display.So Data display is total based 
on your business call (how to display tag data in HTML.. ) 
but here you can optimize first part 
(query for fetching data) as below:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT b.*, t.* FROM blog b inner join tags t on
 b.blog_id= t.blog_id WHERE t.blog_id '" . $id . "')");
```

Please use this.

Comment: Please preview your answer before you post it.

Comment: I think the OP wanted to grab data from BOTH tables!!

Comment: @Strawberry This was example how to use better query And if query is right then obviously OP can select both table columns. If you agree, please accept it.